# Angular2 - a Issue about function scope

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having a trouble when I making my Angular2 Sample with http module,
I basically have this (short-sample) component:

```
app.loginComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
        selector: 'login',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        providers:[lazyResolveService(['app.loginService'])]
    }).Class({
        constructor: [
            ng.http.Http,
            lazyResolveService(['app.loginService']),
            function (http,service) {
                this.result = 'hello world';
                this.httpService = http;
                this.loginService = service;
                // this.loginService = app.loginServiceInjector.get(app.loginService);
            }
        ],

        login: function (username) {
            //this.loginService.printName(username);
            this.httpService.get('http://localhost:8080/xxx/login')
                    .map(function (res) {
                         var str2 = JSON.parse(res._body);
                         return str2.message.securityMessage;
                    })
                    .subscribe(function (res) {
                        console.log(res);
                        console.log(this.result);
                        return this.result = res;
                    });
            console.log(this.result);
        }
    });
```

So, that is just a snippet of my component. And I'm having trouble accessing the local variables from within my login function.
As see, when the code running following function:

```
                 subscribe(function (res) {
                        console.log(this.result);
                        return this.result = res;
                    })
```

it got a result：'undefine',so that means 'this.result' is undefine, and the scope of 'this.result' is not in the loginComponent's constructor function.
so how can I access local variable in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, when I look into Angular2 resource code, I got some inspiration that I should use the key word 'this' better. So I changed my code like follows:

```
    constructor: [
        ng.http.Http,
        lazyResolveService(['app.loginService']),
        function (http,service) {
            var _self = this;
            _self.result = 'hello world';
            _self.httpService = http;
            _self.loginService = service;
            // this.loginService = app.loginServiceInjector.get(app.loginService);
        }
    ],

    login: function (username) {
        //this.loginService.printName(username);
        _self.httpService.get('http://localhost:8080/xxx/login')
                .map(function (res) {
                     var str2 = JSON.parse(res._body);
                     return str2.message.securityMessage;
                })
                .subscribe(function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    console.log(_self.result);
                    return _self.result = res;
                });
        console.log(_self.result);
    }
```

And finally I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

change your subscribe callback to add a [binded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method

```
 .subscribe(function (res) {
                        console.log(res);
                        console.log(this.result);
                        return this.result = res;
                    }.bind(this));
```